# Get elements from list containing string of continuous chars and continuous subsequent element

Tags: python, for-loop, enumerate

I am having list of strings like:

```
my_list = ['abc','bcd','cde','def','efc']
```

If want to get the output based on below conditions:

- characters in the string are continuous. For example: `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, ...
- Subsequent elements in the list are continuous too. For example: `"abc"`, `"bcd"`, "cde", ...
- If any of the above condition is not met, `break` the iteration

For the above example, I need output to be like (along with index of elements):

```
0 abc
1 bcd
2 cde
4 efc
```

Here's the code I tried:

```
lst = ['abc','bcd','cde','def','efc']
for idx, i in enumerate(lst):
    if 'c' in i:
        #here should be the other condition
        print(idx,i)
```

But it prints just these:

```
0 abc
1 bcd
2 cde
```

Comment: why not `def`? it is in also in the continuous pattern or am i missing some logic?

Comment: got it, you need `c` to be also present

Comment: What does "continuous (uninterrupted) index" mean? Do you want to stop if there is no 'c' in it? So maybe adding `else: break` helps?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych you got my point, except that with `else: break` if the first element didn't contain `c` t won't print any thing.

Comment: You haven't mentioned that in your question. There are many ways to interpret it. So you need to provide more details and/or examples.

Comment: @A.RahmanMahmoud, `enumerate(takewhile(lambda x: 'c' in x, lst))`. Imports: [`takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile).

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Hope it's clearer now

Comment: The easiest solution is to introduce the flag `found=False`. Set it to `True` when the first match found. And `break` only if the `flag == True`.

Comment: I edited the question based on your clarification. Please refer the edit for reference on how to write questions and keeping the requirements clear so that it'll be easy for SO community and future site users (PS: I may have missed something from the requirement. Feel free to edit and re-add detail if I missed anything)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the *unicode* code of the char using [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord). In the below example, I am using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate the continuous chars in string, and then matching that their *unicode* code are continuous. Then I am using [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to check that all the unicode codes of string are continuous:

```
my_list = ['abc','bcd','cde','def','efc']

for i, l in enumerate(my_list):
    # check if element is first element in list
    is_first = i == 0

    # check if all the chars are continuous in string
    is_continuous = all(ord(a)+1 == ord(b) for a, b in zip(l, l[1::]))

    # Match the continuation order from previous index element.
    # True, for 1st element
    is_previous_match = is_first or ord(my_list[i-1][0])+1 == ord(l[0])

    if is_continuous and is_previous_match:
        print(i, l)
    else:
        break
```

which will print:

```
0 abc
1 bcd
2 cde
3 def
```

Comment: I think OP means something else - just printing strings if they follow the condition and go in a row in the list, not the actual letters in the strings. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Because he writes about continuous indices, not letters.

Comment: OP's having `if 'c' in i` condition in the code, that makes me think (s)he is looking for this check. and their desired output matches that behaviour. Per the logic in your comment, `def` should also be present in the desired output, right?

Comment: What I mean, is that (s)he is (probably) looking for strings with 'c' in them that go in a row in a list. Not the letters in strings themselves that go alphabetically in a row

Comment: thanks for the well-detailed answer but that only works if `l` has no space in the string, the part  `if 'c' in l` is just an example to make the index break after few matches, it's not the point itself

Comment: @A.RahmanMahmoud add `if not (a.isspace() or b.isspace())` to generator passed to `all()`

Comment: @A.RahmanMahmoud Yes, it doesn't handles that *point* because that information was not shared by you in the question. I added the answer based on my best understanding of what you shared.You should edit your question with all the details so that the SO community can help you in better way

Comment: Question is Updated

Comment: Updated the answer per the new details shared by you in the question. In future you should try to share the all the conditions and details you are looking for, because our answers are going to be based on what you share with us

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a much more simple solution

```
my_list = ['lol','abc','bcd','cd e','def','efc','das da']
index = []
for i,l in enumerate(my_list):
    if 'c' in l:
        index.append(i)
for l in my_list[index[0]:]:
    if 'c' in l:
        print(l)
    else:
        break
abc
bcd
cd e
```

Comment: I've suggested you in comments even more simple, with `takewhile()`. But if you don't need indexes, you can use even simpler option: `print(*takewhile(lambda x: 'c' in x, lst), sep='\n')`